# Interpolation error in angular.js filter when using underscore.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js, interpolation

I'm currently stuck with an error in one of my angular.js filters.
It doesn't block the functionality of the page, but you can see that it's loading slower than usual and it's throwing following error in the console:

> Error: [$interpolate:interr] Can't interpolate:
>   {{ clubs | encounter:match.heimmannschaftsId:match.auswaertsmannschaftsId }}
>   TypeError: _.findWhere(...) is undefined

filter.js:

```
angular.module("terminApp").filter("encounter", function() {

    return function(clubs, home, guest) {
        return _.findWhere(clubs, {id: home}).kurzschreibweise + " : " + _.findWhere(clubs, {id: guest}).kurzschreibweise;
    }

});
```

index.html:

```
<body data-ng-app="terminApp">  
    <div class="news-list-box span-4-12 stadienbox active" style="width: 308px; margin-left:20px;" data-ng-controller="TerminCtrl" data-ng-init="init('DFL-CLU-00000B')">

        <div id="countdown" class="news-2-3 countdown"></div>       

        <div class="teaser d-teaser">

            <div class="span-4-12 stadienbox" data-ng-repeat="match in nextMatches">
                <div class="news-2-3">
                    <div class="line1">
                        <div class="col30">
                            {{ match.wettbewerbsId === "DFL-COM-000001" ? "Bundesliga" : "2. Bundesliga" }}
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="col10">
                            {{ match.geplanteAnstosszeit | date:"dd.MM.yyyy '|' HH:mm" }}
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="col20">
                            {{ clubs | encounter:match.heimmannschaftsId:match.auswaertsmannschaftsId }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>      
</body>
```

I guess it has something to do with underscore not being properly loaded at the time the filter is invoked, but how can I make sure that it is loaded before the filter invocation?
Do I have to outsource this function in a service or is there a better workaround for this problem?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the filter and see what's going on. Maybe underscore is loaded but `_.findWhere()` is returning undefined.

Comment: @Anthony Chu: Ah, indeed. clubs is undefined at this point, because it's loaded via $http.get(). Seems I have to make sure to have some data before the filter invokation.

Comment: Or make the filter tolerate non-existant data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems there is an astoundingly simple solution. Just add an null check for the clubs:

```
return function(clubs, home, guest) {
    if (clubs) {
        return _.findWhere(clubs, {id: home}).kurzschreibweise + " : " + _.findWhere(clubs, {id: guest}).kurzschreibweise;
    }
}
```

The error message should've rather say that the value itself is undefined, not the method call.